# proof "$cos^2(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1+cos(x)}{2}$"

Tags: analysis

I want to proof:

$cos^2(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1+cos(x)}{2}$

I have changed the given eqation $1 = cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)$
$\to$ $cos^2(x) = 1- sin^2(x)$

Then another given eqation:

$cos(2x) = cos^2(x)-sin^2(x)$ $\to$ $-sin^2(x)=cos(2x)-cos^2(x)$

After that I have put those equtions together:

$$cos^2(x)=1-sin^2(x)$$
$$cos^2(x)=1+cos(2x)-cos^2(x)$$

So I have the 1+ {...} structure. How can I go on ?
Or is that the wrong way to proof the equation?

I would really appreciate some hints.

Comment: From the latter equality, $\cos^2(x)=1+\cos(2x)-\cos^2(x)$ you get
$2\cos^2(x)=1+\cos(2x)$ giving $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2.$ Then put $x \to \frac{x}2.$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Isn't it odd how most of the answers skipped the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.  Combine like terms.

$$\cos^2x=1+\cos2x-\cos^2x$$

add $\cos^2x$ to both sides.

$$2\cos^2x=1+\cos2x$$

divide both sides by $2$.
$$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}2$$

Let $x=\frac\theta2$ and you get

> $$\cos^2\frac\theta2=\frac{1+\cos\theta}2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos(2y)=2\cos^2(y)-1$$

Let $2y=x$,

$$\cos(x )= 2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1$$

Hence

$$\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}=\frac{1+2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1}{2}=\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Usually the easiest way to proof trigonometric identities is to use complex exponentials. Here we have $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and thus:

$$ \cos^2(\frac{x}{2})
= \frac{1}{4}(e^{i\frac{x}{2}}+e^{-i\frac{x}{2}})^2
= \frac{1}{4}(e^{ix} + 2+ e^{-ix}) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(x) $$

Answer (score 0):

The simple formula for half angle of cosine is $\cos(x)=\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(x/2)$.

Lets go from LHS to RHS in your question. Aplying the formula I mentioned, $\frac{1+cos(x)}{2}$ becomes $\frac{1+\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(x/2)}{2}$.
If you rewrite 1as $ \cos^2(x/2)+\sin^2(x/2)$ you will get:
$$\frac{\cos^2(x/2)+\sin^2(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(x/2)}{2}$$

$$\frac{2\cos^2(x/2)}{2}$$

$$\cos^2(x/2)$$